# Htaccess Regex - Redirect for urls with plus and percent characters

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, http, redirect

When a URL contains a + or % character, I want to redirect that URL to a php redirection script I have written. Regex (.+)(?:+|%)(.*)? works and finds any URLs that contains + or % but it wont work when used in htaccess like -

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} (.+)(?:\+|%)(.+)?
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /directory/content/my-redirect-rewrite.php [L]
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for taking a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you aren't using the RewriteCond capture groups theres no need for ?: and dont really need the (.+) groups either. Try this, and remove the `R=302` if you don't want it to actually change the url displayed in the browser

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} (\+|\%)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /directory/content/my-redirect-rewrite.php [R=302,NC,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. With this condition (\+|\%) I was able to redirect URLs that had %25 (%) in them, but URLs that have %5B or %5D still cannot be redirected to the script. Sorry if I confused you, but I need to redirect all URLs that have % characters. for example - http://mydomain/vertical%5B1%5D.jpg-210x570.jpg

Comment: no I understood what you meant but now that I'm trying it on my machine I'm seeing the url decoding happens before the rewrite rules apply, does yours do this as well?

Comment: Yes, i resolved the issue with something like this - ["-\*]|\s|\+|,|[:->]|[\[-\^]|[{-~] Is this correct way to do it or is there a better way to find if URL contains a % character?

Comment: As far as I know there is no way to get the raw un-decoded url string, so you'd just have to filter out unacceptable characters with something like RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !([A-z0-9#&\.\?\-]+)